# Updating probability distribution

Tags: probability, bayesian

Suppose I have a probability distribution with some mean and uncertainty. I carry out one experiment and make one observation, then how can I update my distribution based on that one observed result.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem